# Автосохранение файлов в NetBeans

Tags: ide, netbeans

Подскажите есть ли возможность в NetBeans IDE 8.1 автоматически сохранять файлы как в IntelliJ IDEA, т.е. не нажимать постоянно Ctrl+S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо установить плагин AutoSaveModified, который будет сохранять изменённые файлы каждую секунду:

Сервис -> Подключаемые модули -> Вкладка Доступные подключаемые модули

1. Найти плагин AutoSaveModified
2. В колонке Установка поставить галочку
3. Нажать кнопку Установить

[плагин на github](http://github.com/rsmz/AutoSaveModified)

Comment: Вопрос тогда по плагину... A что будет с локальным репозиторием при установке данного плагина (с историей). Как потом по ней откатиться, если она будет сохраняться ежесекундно? И как начнет засира..ся диск, если история будет сохраняться ежесекундно?

Comment: Это уже вопрос к автору плагина. Я только установил, пока рано делать выводы.

Comment: Да нет... Как раз это вопрос к Вам. Вы установили и пользуетесь. Т.е. можете ответить на вопрос и о том, что происходит с историей (локальным репозиторием).